# Session Value is fixed while the value is supposed to be changeable

Tags: php

I got a session called

```
$_SESSION["hi"] = $row['id']; ;
```

when I insert it somewhere it gives me a fixed ID which is 144, while I tried to echo `$row['id']` it's not fixed, it changes.

Note for who doesn't know : `$row['id']` is taken value from sql.

Comment: I think you are assuming that this line `$_SESSION["hi"] = $row['id'];` will cause `$_SESSION["hi"]` to always follow the changing values of `$row['id']` It will not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but why are you using $row['id']?

If you want want to assign a value to the session you use $_SESSION['id'] = 'value'.
If you're using the value somewhere else just put in $_SESSION['id'], assigning it to another variable first is only good for less typing.

Comment: I know the usage of mysqli, however how does this relate to a session? What is your goal with this code?

Comment: Can’t comment with reputation below 150 though. I think you should phrase your question better and not be rude to people trying to help you. Edit: By rude I mean derogatory, also instead of editing to make your code entirely different proves my point of taking your phrasing more serious.